# solo mostrar fecha en la View sin modificar el model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

***e intendado formatear y no me resulto, como puedo hacerlo***

el modelo es generado por el ***framework***   solo debo darle el formato en la view

```
@model IEnumerable<PROGRAM.Models.Lista>

<table>
   <tr >
       <th><b>Fecha Inicio</b></th>
       <th><b>Fecha Final</b></th>
   </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaInicio, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control"})</td>
           <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaFinal, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control"})</td>
           <td>
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                       @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                       @Html.ActionLink("Imprimir", "Imprimir", new { id = item.Id })
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                       @Html.ActionLink("Borrar", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                   </div>
               </div>
           </td>
       </tr>
   }
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***mi intento***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola R. Fernandez, este es el stack de programadores y no de adivinos, si pudieras dar más detalles de lo que buscas de tu código y lo que obtienes podríamos ayudarte mejor, saludos. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utiliza `@Html.ValueFor` ..

```
<td>@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.FechaInicio, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta asignado la propiedad `value` con la fecha formateada directamente en objeto anonimo del `DisplayFor`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaInicio, new { value = Model.FechaInicio.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: de donde sale el `Model` de `value = Model.FechaInicio.ToString`

Comment: Model proviene de la declaracion al inicio de la pagina `@model claseModelo`

Comment: no me funciona aun

Answer (score 1):

Una via para darle formato a fechas dinámicamente sin tener que escribir tanto código es creandote una platilla de muestra ejemplo:

En el directorio Shared dentro de tu carpeta Views en tu proyecto crea una carpeta llamada DisplayTemplates y dentro crea una vista cuyo nombre es igual al definido en tu modelo ejemplo:

suponiendo que tenemos un Modelo llamado Libro:

```
 public class Libro
{
    public int LibroId { get; set; }

    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Autor { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FechaPub { get; set; }       
}
```

como ves en el modelo FechaPub es de tipo DateTime y asi mismo debe estar declarada la fecha en tu caso por eso te muestra la hora en 00:00:00. Puedes aplicarle la anotación `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` encima para que sea de tipo `Date` y aqui es donde viene la magia. Al definirla tipo `Date` vamos a la carpeta que hemos creado en Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates y creamos una vista con el nombre Date.cshtml con el siguiente contenido:

/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Date.cshtml

```
@model DateTime
@Model.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy")
```

De esta forma hemos definido una plantilla para el Helper `@Html.DisplayFor()` que funcioana de esta manera:

todo @Html.DisplayFor() que muestre un campo de tipo Date se va a ver de la forma "dd MMMM, yyyy" en cualquier parte de tu app. espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: no tengo que tocar el modelo, esta generandola el framework

Comment: Alomejor no me hice entender bien. De la forma que te expliqué puedes modificar la forma en que ASP muestra los datos, si no querias tocar el modelo podias cambiar el nombre de la plantilla que te dije por DateTime.cshtml, tambien puedes crear cuantas plantillas quieras para los tipos de datos que desees mostrar de una forma diferente a como lo hace el framework: int, string, etc.